# Complex Json schema into custom spark dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Ok so I'm getting a big Json string from an API call, and I want to save some of that string into Cassandra. I'm trying to parse the Json string into a more table like structure, but with only some fields. The overall schema looks like this:

[image: printSchema()]

And I want my table structure using regnum, date and value fields. 
With `sqlContext.read.json(vals).select(explode('register) as 'reg).select("reg.@attributes.regnum","reg.data.date","reg.data.value").show` I can get a table like this:

[image: table]

But as you can see date and value fields are arrays. I would like to have one element per record, and duplicate the corresponding regnum for each record. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your `DataFrame` to `Dataset` then `flatMap` on it.

```
 df.select("reg.@attributes.regnum","reg.data.date","reg.data.value")
   .as[(Long, Array[String], Array[String])]
   .flatMap(s => s._2.zip(s._3).map(p => (s._1, p._1, p._2)))
```

Comment: Awesome dude, works like a charm. I really need to polish my scala skills. Thanks.

Comment: I just ran into a another bump. What if I have some records that are [(Long, Array[String], Array[String])] and some that are [(Long,String,String)] ?? How can I make a case mapping? Thanks again!

Comment: Is it in the same column?

Comment: Yes, second and third columns may or may not be arrays, and if they are arrays the size is dynamic.