# Apply custom schema to post response JSON from rest api using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, spark-structured-streaming

I have tried to send the json request and receive the json response and I am converting the json contents to Dataframe but the schema is string for all attributes.Is there anyway to apply my custom schema to the json response that is stored in datasets using scala and spark.

```
val inputStream = entity.getContent()
content = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString
inputStream.close
}
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
println(content)

val rootelem = "data"
var JsonDF : Dataframe = null;
if (rootelem.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL"))
{
jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(Seq(content).toDS)

}
```

else{jsonDF=sqlContext.read.json(Seq(content).toDS).select(explode(col(rootelem)). 
   as("child").select(col("child.*"))

```
jsonDF.show()
}}
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212966/complex-json-schema-into-custom-spark-dataframe

Comment: @Prateek Prateek this is for JSON file but in my case I am getting response directly from rest post API and I am saving it to dataframe dynamically but the data types are not matching.For file level custom schema is applicable but for getting response and storing it dynamically into dataframe is not matching the case as of JSON files do.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own StructType or have to create Struct type dynamically  and then using your Json and structtype create the data frame.  Example :

```
 val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("num", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("letter", StringType, true)
  )
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  schema
)
```

Please check this to create struct type dynamically [Dynamically build case class or schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138397/dynamically-build-case-class-or-schema)

Comment: this is only working for static files\data.But for dynamically collecting the json response and applying the schema is not working kindly have a look at the above code.